# Package installation fails to org's with Shared Activies disabled. "Invalid field TaskWhoIds for SObject Task"

Tags: apex, managed-package, tasks, dynamic, shared-activities

I have a problem where the package installation fails to organisations that has Shared Activity disabled. As far as I understand the case is that TaskWhoIds is not available on orgnaisations that has Shared Activity disabled. However as we have a managed package I have to be able to support both options.

I'm looking for a way to get around this and try to use the TaskWhoIds field in the for loop but have not been able to find a solution.

Hopefully someone has stepped into this same problem before and has managed to solve it.

Here's the code, Thanks.

```
    List<Task> taskRelations = Database.query('SELECT Id, TaskWhoIds FROM Task WHERE Id IN :tasks LIMIT 5000');                                        

    Map<Id, List<Id>> taskRelationByTaskId = new Map<Id, List<Id>>();

    for(Task tk : tasks){
        taskRelationByTaskId.put(tk.Id, new List<Id>());    
    }

    for(Task tr : taskRelations){
        for(Id i : tr.TaskWhoIds){ // This is where the package installation fails on ORGs that doesn't have Shared Activity enabled.
            taskRelationByTaskId.get(tr.Id).add(i);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have come across issues like this before and the simplest solution I found (couple of years ago now) was to have a base package which contains the 'non TaskWhoIds' field and an extension that has the extra functionality. Read about it [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/dev_packages_extensible.htm). Swop GE/PE/UE editions for Shared Activity active/disabled.

Alternatively have 2 packages, one for each type.

Comment: Would this approach work with our package being in AppExchange?

Comment: I think it would although I haven't reviewed the documentation for a while.